# Hadoop for processing data from Apache solr

Tags: java, solr, hadoop, mapreduce

I have to process some huge amount of data.I would like it to be processed using distributed computing(Scalable).
I am fetching data from apache Solr.On passing a particular input i get a huge dataset  from apache solr.For each record in this dataset i will  pass the primary key to a REST api to obtain some information which will be  attached to the record.Then each record will undergo some update.Each updated object in final huge collection will be written as seperate xml files into a folder.

Is hadoop applicable in this particular scenario?.I have seen the wordcount sample in hadoop mapreduce documentation.I tried to think of my situation in a similar way in which map emitted by map reduce for 2 nodes will be

```
Node1 - Map<InputIdToSolr1,Set<RecordsFromSolr1to500>>
Node2 - Map<InputIdToSolr1,Set<RecordsFromSolr500to1000>>
```

Then this results will be combined by the reduce function in hadoop.Unlike wordcount my nodes will have only one element in map for each node.I am not sure if using hadoop makes sense.
What are other options/open source java projects i can use to  scale the processing of records.I have seen Terracotta from spring but it seems to be a commercial application.

Comment: I see no reason as to why it will not work. I'm working on a similar scenario and getting results from a REST Based Service and passing it to Hadoop

Comment: I dint say its not working.I am just analysing everything before starting.Can u tell me if my approach with hadoop in this situation is correct/not

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the scale of scalabilty you are looking for, but I would first try a multithreaded solution on a multicore box.

If the performance does not match expectations, and you have the flexibility of getting more hardware and instances of your application, you may start thinking of a Map-Reduce solution.

Terracota is not from Spring/SpringSource/VMWare, although it's proprietary and commercial.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using NoSQL databases?
The decision of which one to use really depends on the shape of your data.
To check them out (all open source):

- [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)
- [Redis](http://redis.io/)
- [Riak](http://wiki.basho.com/Riak.html)
- [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)
- [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/)
- [CouchBase](http://www.couchbase.com/)

[More about NoSQL databases.](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/)

*Edit:*
I've just stumbled upon [this webinar](http://info.couchbase.com/WhyNoSQLWhyNowWebinar4_WebinarRegistrationPage.html) from Couchbase and Cloudera (Hadoop solution & support company) where they're going to discuss NoSQL + Hadoop usage.

Comment: I am already using mongodb.It is not fetching the data i am worried about.My concern is processing of millions of records fetched from mongodb

Comment: So your data is already in Mongo and its [Aggregation Framework](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework) and [MongoDb's MapReduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce) isn't enough for some reason?

Comment: yes.I have couple of other things to do in processing each record

Answer (score 0):

The task is sounds suited for Hadoop's MapReduce.
More then that - Lucene and Hadoop are created by the same person Doug Cutting.
In you case you can consider different levels of integration. Simplest one will be put your datasets into HDFS, then select / write input format suited your data format and in the Mapper make Your REST call to complete the record. 
 
If you have a lot of different, but relatively simple processing, I would suggest considering representing your data as Hive tables - or from HDFS, or in the SOLR.
I am not adept of SOLR architecture, but, if your Using apache nutch together with SOLR - you might have hadoop integrated within and may use it.